# Should I use an access control on a shared structure between threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, posix

I'm writing a small piece of software in C using the pthread library.
I have a bunch of threads that need write access to a shared structure containing a dynamically allowed char array **but** I can guarantee that two different threads will never try to access the same element of this array. My question is: should I use something like a semaphore or a mutex or isn't it necessary?

Comment: Q: Should I use [a lock] if it isn't necessary?  A: No, of course not :).  Q: If I can guarantee that two different threads can never access the same element of this array, do I need a lock?  A: If you can guarantee the same "entity" (e.g. array element or pointer) will never be updated concurrently by more than one thread, No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your threads only read information, then no lock is needed.

If your threads modify information other threads don't see, no lock is needed.

If there is a single place that can be modified by one thread and used by others, you need to use a mutex.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the data are not shared between the threads and since the data is not shared between the threads, no synchronization mechanismn is required.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you answered the question yourself!

The purpose of mutexes is to protect against concurrent access of different threads on some resources. If you can guarantee that by design your threads will never concurrently access (read or write) the same memory area then you don't need mutex protection.